# Blazor Modal declaration throws CS8625 upon compilation

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I'm utilizing the Blazorise Modal feature ([as seen here](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/modal)). I'm following the documentation via the following code:

```html
<Modal @ref="ModalRef1">
  <ModalContent Centered>
    <ModalHeader>
      <ModalTitle>Sample Title</ModalTitle>
    </ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
      <Field>
        <FieldLabel>Sample Field Content</FieldLabel>
      </Field>
    </ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter>
      <Button Color="Color.Warning" Clicked="@HideModal1">OK</Button>
    </ModalFooter>
  </ModalContent>
</Modal>
```

With the following instance declaration:

```cs
@code{
  private Modal ModalRef1 = new Modal();
}
```

For some reason, the HMTL  declaration throws a "Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type" error for each HTML  declaration. Given that I'm using a LOT of Modal dialogs throughout the project, you can see how this would get annoying. How do I fix this? `#pragma warning disable CS8625` doesn't work, and the Modal C# class has no other constructor than the default.

Comment: @HenkHolterman terminology specifics aside, the warnings are annoying and I'd like to get rid of it. The team wants a clean-compiling project and a warning and an error are the same thing in their eyes.

Comment: Try changing "private Modal ModalRef1 = new Modal();" to just "private Modal ModalRef1;", which is what is shown in the Blazorise example code.

Comment: Well, still: no repro. That and the fact that we're missing a `/` makes me think we are not looking at real code here. The error has been buried under the carpet.

Comment: @Roberto that didn't work - the warning is generated at the `<Modal>` tag in the HTML.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm avoiding posting actual code since it's proprietary. This is the same code that I have, but replicated with placeholder values.

Comment: Copied the given code to a new file and I'm still getting the same issue. If it's an un-reproduceable issue, then looks like an SOL moment.

Comment: Have you tried giving the `Centered` parameter a value? I guess you have NRT enabled and it doesn't like you not providing an explicit value for that bool.

Comment: @MisterMagoo I don't believe there's an option to do so. According to the documentation, it's just a styling flag passed into the HMTL `<Modal>` tag.

Comment: Don't new it up. What version of core? Try asking questions here: https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/217

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to make the field type nullable.

```
@code {
    private Modal? ModalRef1;
}
```

Your project probably has `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in your .csproj file. This setting makes all types to be treated as non-nullable and you have to be explicit when you want them to accept null. The Modal's `@ref` attribute accepts a `Modal?` parameter and you were passing `Modal`. That's why you get the warning.